# Existence of relative equivariant minimal models

Tags: equivariant-homotopy, rational-homotopy-theory

In [equivariant rational homotopy theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/equivariant%20rational%20homotopy%20theory) the existence of minimal models (i.e. the equivariant generalization of minimal Sullivan models) has been established by Triantafillou ([jstor:1999119](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1999119)) and Scull ([doi:10.1090/S0002-9947-01-02790-8](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-01-02790-8), [doi:10.1090/S0002-9947-07-04421-2](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-07-04421-2)), at least for finite equivariance groups and for fixed locus-wise simply connected $G$-spaces (and of rational finite type, of course).

Has anyone worked out the proof for the more general existence of **relative** minimal models in equivariant RHT?

I have checked with the above authors, and the answer seems to be No, but just thought I'd check here, in case anyone has the proof in their drawer.

Comment: On a related note, I am wondering if Scull's model category structure (https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2008-360-05/S0002-9947-07-04421-2/) generalizes from orbit categories to tom Dieck's "fundamental categories" of G-spaces (as recalled here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/orbit%20category#FundamentalCategoryOfAGSpace).